# Meaning of 史上 in this blog

Tags: meaning

I'm trying to translate this [blog](https://lineblog.me/nagatatakato/archives/932547.html).

The blogger talked about the album of Abe Mao called "Pop (ポっぷ)".

> 阿部真央**史上**、一番聞いてるアルバムだなぁ。名曲揃いだ
>
> ちなみに今流れてるのは"もうひとつのMY BABY"です
>
> 初めて聞いた阿部真央さんの曲は"貴方の恋人になりたいのです"なんだよね。それもポっぷに入ってる！！

According to [Jisho](http://jisho.org/search/%E5%8F%B2%E4%B8%8A),

> 史上 = in history; ever; historical​

Since this album is just another studio album and was not classified as "best album",

I was quite confused what does 阿部真央**史上** mean in his blog?

Is it possible that it was an abbreviation of some sorts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

史上 on its own can mean "in the history", but it can be combined with many nouns to mean "in the history of ～". For example you can say アメリカ史上最も偉大な大統領 (the greatest president in the history of America).

So 阿部真央史上 also literally means "in the history of Mao Abe," which is already a bit colloquial usage of 史上 (it can be used in ads but not in formal documents). However, in this context, it doesn't even refer to her actual career as a musician, but refers to the author's own personal experience concerning Mao Abe. The author is comparing his memory concerning Mao Abe to "history." This is not a proper way of using 史上, but we can feel he has liked the musician for a long time. 一番聞いてる means the author himself is listening to the album most as compared to her previous albums.